# WWW::Mechanize follows a second redirect after six seconds

Tags: perl, redirect, www-mechanize

I am using Perl with the [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) module to submit a form to a webpage and save the result to a file. I know how to submit forms and save the data, but I can't save data after this six-second redirection.

After the form is submitted, the page is redirected to a page that says

```
Results should appear in this window in approximately 6 seconds...
```

and it is redirected again to the page with the result I want. My script can follow the first redirection, but not the second, and there is no link says something like *"click here if not redirected"*.

Here is my script

```perl
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);

$mech->get( "http://tempest.wellesley.edu/~btjaden/TargetRNA2/index.html");

$result = $mech->submit_form(
    form_number =>  1,
    fields      =>  {
        text    => 'Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655',
        sequence    => '>RyhB' . "\n" .
                        'GCGATCAGGAAGACCCTCGCGGAGAACCTGAAAGCACGACATTGCTCACATTGCTTCCAGTATTACTTAGCCAGCCGGGTGCTGGCTTTT',
    }    
);
$mech->save_content(result);
```

Comment: It is impolite of you to present code in such a mess and ask for help with it. It wouldn't hurt you to indent it properly so that it was at least readable. As it stands it's a mess.

Comment: The *Wellesley College* site doesn't appear to like the sequence ID `>RyhB` in the RNA sequence field. It would help if you posted the *actual* code that you're having problems with.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is extract the redirect URL and ran it manually:

Try this:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

$mech->get( "http://tempest.wellesley.edu/~btjaden/TargetRNA2/index.html");

$result = $mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1, 
    fields      => 
    {
        text        => 'Escherichia coli str. K-12 substr. MG1655', 
        sequence    => '>RyhB GCGATCAGGAAGACCCTCGCGGAGAACCTGAAAGCACGACATTGCTCACATTGCTTCCAGTATTACTTAGCCAGCCGGGTGCTGGCTTTT',
    }
);

my $content =  $mech->content;
my $url1 = 'http://tempest.wellesley.edu/~btjaden/cgi-bin/';
my ($url2) = $content =~ /URL=(targetRNA2\.cgi?.+)?">/;

$mech->get($url1.$url2);

$mech->save_content(result);
```

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* Perl program. There is very little point in declaring variables with `my` without `use strict` in place.

Answer (score 0):

### WWW::Mechanize and meta refresh

Does the "6 seconds" contain something line the line below?  [You may use `save_content` method of WWW::Machenize to save page to file]

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

YES=>

Take a look at sources of [WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::FollowMetaRedirect](http://search.cpan.org/~ryochin/WWW-Mechanize-Plugin-FollowMetaRedirect-0.03/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Plugin/FollowMetaRedirect.pm).
It shows how WWW::Mechanize may follow [meta refresh with redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).
It may quite likely solve your problem.

Comment: This is rather like a link-only answer. Might want to add some of the details from these links into your post.

Comment: It is not cost effective without knowing which "delayed redirection" method is used by the page e.g. I have seen redirections based on javascript only,